# Pegar informações JSON e inserir no html com loop usando getJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

Seguinte, tenho uma tabela numa página html, exemplo:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>nome</th>
                <th>e-mail</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith@mail</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson@email</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

E eu tenho um script em php que me retorna nome e email de usuário no formato JSON, gostaria de saber como eu posso pegar as informações do php via getJSON e fazer um loop para inserir na tabela ao carregar a página?

```
$(document).ready(function(){


});
```

Comment: Podes colocar um pedaço/exemplo do JSON que tens?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.get("pagina.php", {"parametros": "valores", "parametros2": "valores"}, function(data)
{

var retorno = JSON.parse(data);//este retorno sera um array ou um object entao e so usar um loop for para varre-lo.


});
```